# Table '***.tx_scheduler_task' doesn't exist after "composer typo3/cms-scheduler"

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I'm using Typo3 v10.4.9 in composer mode. It seems its missing one of the core extensions "sheduler". I was trying to install it via composer with follow command:
`composer require typo3/cms-scheduler`

Everything runs fine, no errors. Now, when i try to visit the backend, i got following error:

> Table '***.tx_scheduler_task' doesn't exist | Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\TableNotFoundException thrown in > file /***/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php in line 46. Requested  URL: https://***/typo3/index.php?route=%2Fmain&token=--AnonymizedToken-- -
> ...
> Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT COUNT(`uid`) FROM `tx_scheduler_task` WHERE `deleted` = 0':

I'm not sure, what i'm doing wrong here. I just followed the official steps to how you install an extension in composer mode.

Comment: Use Admin Tools / Maintenance / Analyze Database Structure to update your database

Comment: Ok, thanks, works! I didn't thought about that. Is there a way via console to trigger that? Its strange that composer require automatically enables the extension without setting up the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Web: Open the Admin Tools Module > Maintenance > Analyze Database Structure (as mentioned by Simon Gilli in the comments)
2. Console: Use typo3_console by Helhum to update the database schema:
   Execute command: `typo3cms database:updateschema "\*.add,\*.change"`.
   See: https://docs.typo3.org/p/helhum/typo3-console/master/en-us/CommandReference/DatabaseUpdateschema.html